# Access attributes or use getter methods?

Tags: c++

As a C++ beginner, I didn't thought about that much until now, but if I want to access an attribute **from inside** a class itself, should I access the attribute directly or use a getter function?

```
class foo
{
public:
  int getVal();
  void bar();
private:
  int val;
}

foo::bar()
{
  int val = this->getVal();
  // or
  int val2 = this->val;
}
```

I would like to know that for

a) what is better design and (more importantly for me)

b) any performance differences (maybe because of the overhead calling the function)?

I normally use the getter method even inside the class in case I ever want to rename the attribute. But now I'm writing a method, which will access the attribute quite (very) often.

Comment: Note: these are fields, attributes mean something different in C++

Comment: Thanks for the info, Nicholas! Years ago I have learned that variables and functions are being called attributes and methods inside a class (this was teached in my education class back then for C++). I wonder why they didn't told me that they are called fields. :-/

Answer (score 2):

It depends. Getters may have synchronization and if called from a method that is already holding the lock may deadlock the application. Or, on the contrary, getters may count/log access to the resource. Or even, the class may be an interface on the byte buffer and getters/setters dynamically unmarshal/marshal the wire data, in which case calling getters and setters is unavoidable.

The only universal rule - be consistent across the code base and try to not overcomplicate the design.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, getter and setters are used to hide complexity, or better saying, to abstract details from out of a class. So they are not mandatory for using inside a class.

Simply I can say, if you don't have a getter, you don't need to make that, for using inside of the class.
But if you have a getter, you should always use that, whether inside or outside of the class, as you might have applied some logic to the raw value inside getter.

Comment: @StanE, if your getters are inlined -- no performance hit. Otherwise, it depends on optimizations. Without optimizations you are incurring extra function call

Comment: @StanE performance difference is just function call, that may not be such important in regular applications, except you are developing an operating system or a real time system

Answer (score 1):

Inside the class always use the attribute itself. The reason you have a getter is to make a certain value available to other classes. Be careful with automatically making getters for every attribute you use. It is considered bad design to expose the inner workings of a class. Sometimes it makes sense to make an attribute available, sometimes it is just for internal use and other classes have no business inspecting them.

If you like to know more about this google "getters setters evil" Some of the articles you may find are quite extreme but they will explain why they feel that way.

Comment: Haters please comment

Comment: "The reason you have a getter is to make a certain value available to other classes" No! If that would be the only purpose of a getter one could simply make the member public. The reason to use a getter is to be in control how that value can be accessed from outside the class.

Comment: @tobi303 I disagree....using a getter every time makes changes easier in the future...it makes it easy to have inheritance (I mean how do I override a variable?)....and it is very useful for debugging

Comment: [Here](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/09/16/getters-and-setters-are-evil.html) is a good article

Comment: @tobi303 You are right, I should have worded that better. Although making it public also means you can set it, so in that sense the getter is used to be able to access a normally private value.

Comment: @DarthRubik i dont know in what points you disagree with me, because I do not disagree with anything you mention ;). Actually my last comment I used a bit the wrong words and I would like to remove the last words ("from outside the class") but it is too late to edit, getters let you control how that value is accessed be it from within or from outside the class does not matter

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with @user3535256. Getters and setters should also be used inside private class functions. The idea behind getters and setters is to make code changes nice and easy. @StanE think of a situation where you're using your class member variable without getter functions and after some time you'd like to change the name to be more meaningful. This example forces you to change the member name in each place it's used. In case of using getter method for your variable only class getter function will be affected by this code change.

Comment: Like I said, I normally use getters and setters because of that reason. I'm more interested in the performance implications if they are called very often in a short time.

Comment: We have IDE's for renaming things inside a class. If the new name is better it should be used everywhere in the class. It would be extremely confusing if you would use getX() to get a variable inside a class that is actually called Y now.

Comment: @StanE getter should be mark as const method, compilers are smart enough to do the job without performance impact.

Comment: What if you want to change the name of the getter?... You will still need to change it in each place. Like user3535256 said, IDEs nowadays handle these things

Comment: @InnocentBystander well if you change it in a way, that you need to change the getter name for it you end up in the same situation as you were using variable without getter. But in most cases(from my experience) you just need variable rename, because you added similar private member.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the internals of your class. Suppose you have a simple class that holds a value and you want to count how often that value was accessed but there are different getter methods (I have to admit it is a quite contrived example). Instead of doing the bookkeeping in each of the methods it is easier to do it only once and use the getter also inside the class:

```
class CountedValue{
    private:
        int value;
        int counter;
    public:
        CountedValue() : value(0),counter(0) {}
        int getValue() const {
            counter++; 
            return value; 
        }
        int getMinusValue() const { 
            return - getValue(); 
        }
        // ... possibly more methods to retrieve the value
        int getCounter() const { return counter;}
}
```

Actually with setters the benefit of using them also inside the class becomes more evident. You usually want to do bookkeeping and define the invariants of a member only once and not each time it can change. 
For example:

```
class Rational {
    private:
        int numerator;
        int denominator;
    public:
        void setNumerator(int n) { numerator = n; }
        void setDenominator(int d) {
            assert(d != 0 && "division by zero");
            denominator = d;
        }
        void set(int n, int d) {
            setNumerator(n);
            setDenominator(n);  // no need to check for 0 again
        }
  }
```

Comment: In your first example ythe getter has side effects which I think violates the CQS principle. In your second example I feel you shouldn't be able to set a numerator or denominator individually. In fact I would argue that you would need to set them both in the constructor and the class should only have  methods that operate on the Rational like add or multiply.

Comment: @user3535256 well that are just examples. It is the first time i hear about the CQS principle, and actually I disagree, because increasing the counter is not a command from the caller but some internal bookkeeping. Anyhow counting how often a getter is called is sheer nonsense ;). Maybe these are really not the best examples

Comment: I'm sorry if it seems I'm nitpicking, I understand these are just examples. But my point is that I really think there are no good examples of when it is useful to use gettters or setters for fields inside the same class. I'm open to suggestions though ;)

Comment: @Alfred_P Imho best example for using setters inside a class is when some other object needs to get notified (e.g. via a callback) whenever a certain field changes its value. In that case you want to notify that object only once in the setter and call that setter whenever you change the value. I just didnt know how to put that in a nice short example. Maybe I will edit the answer later